# Is there a way to specify where (in another file) The node.js module FS writes the data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an issue where when I use the fs method `fs.appendFileSync(example.json, jsonString, {'flags': 'a+'});` it will write the data to the JSON file... But not in the array I need the data to be in... When I run the code the JSON files contents will look like this
`{people:[ {where I want the data to go} ] }{data is written here}` I have no idea as to how to specify that i need the data to be inside the array people... I also have the issue of multiple objects being in the array... They need to have commas how would I also do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the content of the file by appending to it. You have to read all the data into a object, modify it an then overwrite the contents. See this for a general idea.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const data = require('./file.json') // node will parse json automatically
data.people.push({}) // the new data you want in the array
fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: You literally just responded what I was reading from the documentation... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

method -1
read that file in some variable.
then add your data in that variable which is json.
then rewrite file.

method - 2
use fs.write
provide position where data need to be added.

```
fs.writeSync(fd, string, position)
```

position will be fixed and calculate it based on your json.

Comment: Method 1 I am going to use now but i am going to use method 2 sometime down the road thank you for the help!!!

Comment: in method 1 - whole file is being stored in memory.. so if it is some big file then will consume lot of memory

Comment: Its just supposed to be storage and its hosted online with no data cap... But thank you!